# integer validation for text fields in yii

Tags: validation, yii

I had a text field in my form like

```
$form->textField($model,'test',array('required'=>'true'))
```

The validation works for required field. Is any way to give validation for an integer like this . I tried Like

```
$form->textField($model,'test',array('required'=>'true','integer'=>'true'));
```

But it doesn't work. Is any other way to do it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

in your model under `rules()` function add the rule like below

```
array('test', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
```

Comment: But is any way to do it in form itself like for required validation

Comment: how to validate for non required field?

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done in the rules.  Your code as provided was:

```
$model = "someString";
$form->textField($model,'test',array('required'=>'true'));
```

This code itslef will not cause the field to be required, all it will do is add a required attribute with a value of true to the generated HTML, e.g.:

```
<input name='someString' required='true'>test</input>
```

That's not going to cause validation to run.  Validation will run because of rules defined in the model, and can not be added during the view stage.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use like this -

```
array('number_value', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[0-9]+$/', 'message'=>"{attribute} no. Invalid."),
```